# Constraining Type Signatures for Left and Right

Tags: scala

Given the following AST for `Success` and `Failure`:

```
sealed trait Success
case object FooGood extends Success
case object BarGood extends Success

sealed trait Failure
case object FooBad extends Failure
case object BarBad extends Failure
```

And the method signature:

```
def go[A <: Failure, B <: Success](x: Int): Either[A, B] = ???
```

However, I'd like to constrain the `Left` and `Right` types to be specific to `Foo` or `Bar`.

But the following code compiles (against my wishes):

```
scala> go[FooBad.type, BarGood.type](5)
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

How can I achieve this constraint at compile-time?

Comment: Why not using trait Foo and Bar, with this definition : def go[F](x : Int) : Either[Failure with F, Success with F] = ???

Comment: I agree that it should compile. I was not claiming that it should **not** compile. My question is how to write a `go` implementation (in a generic way) that will fail to compile if a `Bar` doesn't appear on both sides, i.e. `Right` and `Left`, or vice-versa for `Foo`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that relies on a type class. Of note is that it does not require to manually define new type class instances for each (pair of) AST node.
It does involve introducing a common super type for each pair (though you don't technically **have** to use it as a base class, it's merely used as a tag type).

```
sealed trait Success[T]
abstract sealed class Foo
abstract sealed class Bar
case object FooGood extends Foo with Success[Foo]
case object BarGood extends Bar with Success[Bar]
sealed trait Failure[T]
case object FooBad extends Foo with Failure[Foo]
case object BarBad extends Bar with Failure[Bar]

@annotation.implicitNotFound("Expecting reciprocal Failure and Success alternatives, but got ${A} and ${B}")
trait IsGoodAndBadFacet[A,B]
implicit def isGoodAndBadFacet[T,A,B](implicit e1: A <:< Failure[T], e2: B<:<Success[T]): IsGoodAndBadFacet[A,B] = null

def go[A, B](x: Int)(implicit e: IsGoodAndBadFacet[A,B]): Either[A, B] = ???
```

Repl test:

```
scala> go[FooBad.type, BarGood.type](5)
<console>:17: error: Expecting reciprocal Failure and Success alternatives, but got FooBad.type and BarGood.type
              go[FooBad.type, BarGood.type](5)
                                           ^

scala> go[FooBad.type, FooGood.type](5)
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  at .go(<console>:11)
  ... 33 elided

scala> go[BarBad.type, BarGood.type](5)
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
  at scala.Predef$.$qmark$qmark$qmark(Predef.scala:225)
  at .go(<console>:11)
  ... 33 elided
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that compiler doesn't know that `FooGood` is somehow related to `FooBad`, so you need to hint it somehow.

Here's what I came up with, though I admit it is not very elegant:

```
trait Grouping[B, G]

object FooHelper {
  implicit object fooGrouping Grouping[FooBad.type, FooGood.type]
}

object BarHelper {
  implicit object barGrouping Grouping[BarBad.type, BarGood.type]
}

def go[A <: Failure, B <: Success](x: Int)(implicit ev: Grouping[A, B]): Either[A, B] = ???


import FooHelper._
import BarHelper._

// the following two type check
go[FooBad.type, FooGood.type](5)
go[BarBad.type, BarGood.type](5)

// while these two do not
go[FooBad.type, BarGood.type](5)
go[BarBad.type, FooGood.type](5)
```

As you can see the hint is implemented by creating a `Grouping` and putting *correct* groupings into the implicit scope. The problem with this approach is that the user might create his own groupings which might not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to restrict output type to be pair of `Success` / `Failure` by introducing the type parameter :

```
sealed trait Success[T]
sealed trait Failure[T]

sealed trait Foo
sealed trait Bar

case object FooGood extends Success[Foo]
case object BarGood extends Success[Bar]

case object FooBad extends Failure[Foo]
case object BarBad extends Failure[Bar]

def go[T, A <: Failure[T], B <: Success[T]](x: Int): Either[A, B] = ???
```

But! This makes sense only if you will create some concrete implementation which provides type `T`, because other way it is meaningless to create such signature.

I can see any utility for this as a part of interface, which constrains result of `go`, like this:

```
trait Paired[T] {                  
  type A <: Failure[T]            
  type B <: Success[T]            
  def go(x: Int): Either[A, B]    
}
```

If you want to supply types explicitly (but how will you create implementation for this?) - answer with providing implicit grouping is very reasonable.

Comment: Adding: `sealed trait FooBarParent` (which `Foo` and `Bar` extend), and then: `def go[T <: FooBarParent, ... rest of your code ...` would add that constraint?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Logically it would consume then any `FooBarParent`. Btw, if you'd explain in the question how will you plan to use your code, it might lead people to better propositions. Even if you happen to declare some signature that satisfies you in single method - you cannot give it any concrete implementation, except `???` or other exception. What is the use case?